# Can't delete test folder in Windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7

Ihave a project setup like this

```
project/src/test/python/main.py
project/test-output
```

i want the main-testscript to delete and then recreate the test-output folder.

So i put this code there.

```
if os.path.exists("test-output"):
    shutil.rmtree("test-output")
os.mkdir("test-output")
```

But when i run it with

```
d:\projects\thisproject>python src\test\python\main.py
```

I get a access denies error from windows. [Error 5]

How to fix this?

the mkdir command works fine tough.

Comment: Access denied on what command (rmtree or mkdir)? And on what path (d:\projects\thisproject?)? Please include the *full* traceback.

Answer (score 2):

I have recently seen this behaviour of shutil.rmtree() myself under Windows 7, also when creating and destroying test folders from unit tests. And, no, there was nothing having an active reference to the directory or anything in it, not even an explorer window. My 'solution' (if you can call it that) was to do:

```
shutil.rmtree("my/test/dir", ignore_errors=True)
```

Not exactly a thing of beauty, but it solved the problem for me.

By the way, this was a 64 bit Windows 7 machine, and on an SSD. A co-worker reported the same problem with shutil.rmtree() when deleting a directory on a Windows share on another machine. I'm getting a feeling that Windows is caching things here, if only briefly.

Answer (score 1):

Windows only marks the file/directory as 'delete on close', unlike Unix where an unlink removes an item from view right away. See the documentation of the [Remove Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365488%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function from MSDN. So if any process (e.g. an explorer window, full text indexer or a virus scanner) still has an open handle to the file, you fail.

So even if you ignore errors on delete you will then fail in the `os.mkdir` step. One simple fix would be to not recreate the directory, but simply delete all its content. Another is to wait and retry the operation after a few seconds.

The best way around that restriction would be to use a different output folder (via `tempfile.makedtemp()`) for every run. Your delete than kicks in when the last reference goes away, but your recreate never fails.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely something is using the folder - either by having a file opened that is located inside that folder or by having the folder or a subfolder of it as its current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def renewDir(name):
    while 1:
        try:
            if os.path.exists(name):
                shutil.rmtree(name)
            os.makedirs(name)   
            break
        except:
            pass
```